# A function that generates a different number at each call: should I pass the engine, the distribution or both?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, thread-safety, std

I have some difficulties to understand exactly the role of the distribution regarding a given random engine. Suppose I want to write a function `f(/* Arguments */)` that returns a new random number at each call using a `std::mt19937` engine and a `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>`. I want this function to be thread safe. My question is the following: should I pass by reference to this function, the engine, the distribution or both ?

Comment: why not use a local engine in each thread instead of sharing it across threads?

Comment: Yes of course, I will use a local engine for each thread if necessary. But as I do not understand why the () operator of distribution is not const, I do not know whether I should also create a distribution per thread, an pass it to the function...

Comment: the distribution takes a reference to the engine, which has state. It's the engine that you need to either make thread-local, or wrap some locking around it.

Comment: I use an engine per thread and a distribution per thing that needs the given distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible for distributions to cache some state and thereby reduce the frequency of calls to the engine to obtain entropy. For example, the [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_transform) maps two samples from a uniform distribution into two samples from a normal distribution. It's possible to implement `std::normal_distribution` via Box-Muller so that it makes two calls to the engine for every second call to the distribution.

Ideally you would store an engine and distribution per-thread - or more granular, but certainly not less - and pass a lambda or `std::function<int()>` to your function `f` to insulate it from the details of how the random numbers are obtained.

Comment: I thought the distribution was just a stateless algorithm that takes a number from the engine (which in turn does have state). Do you have a Standard quote that explains the latitude a distribution has?

Comment: @TemplateRex C++11 26.5.1.6 Random number distribution requirements [rand.req.dist] in its entirety. Specifically from Table 118: (a) `operator()` is not required to be `const`, (b) `reset()` has effects: "Subsequent uses of [the distribution] do not depend on values produced by any engine prior to invoking reset.", (c) `operator<<` and `operator>>` write/read "a textual representation for the parameters and the additional internal data of [a distribution instance]."

Comment: @TemplateRex, that is also my (cursory) reading at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random)